# 2D chars and numbers array

Tags: c, matrix, numbers, 2d, character

I'm trying to solve a problem in **C**.

It requires me to register some chars and numbers in a matrix A[n][n] and then print them.
It must be something like this:
A[3][3]:


a D g 2

T 1 c v

G J k L

N 6 f Z

I checked the web and... no solution. I only find arrays of chars.

```
int n = 3;
char matrixA[n][n];

int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%c ", &matrixA[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

what I get is an error:

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: `A[4][4]` has space for 16 elements. Your data has 25 elements. You need to define the array as `A[5][5]`.

Comment: I tried this: char matrixA[n][n];

int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%c ", &matrixA[i][j]);
        }
    }

Comment: also matrixA[i][j]=getchar();

Comment: Remove the trailing space in the `scanf` format, and add a leading space instead.

Comment: @Himanshu sorry I pasted a part of my code here (I needed to translate and I mispeled, edited)

Comment: is there any way for chars like for int? I mean  int i, j; for(i=0; i<n; i++){ for(j=0; j<n; j++){ scanf("%c ", &matrixA[i][j]); } } this should work for ints (if I typed %d), but what about chars?

Comment: So what is the problem in `%c` , you can save integer in char array and print also with `%c` .

Comment: Updated my question. I think now my problem is readable.

Comment: what I get is an error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: Where do you set `n`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY not n is the problem.. n in my code exists some where :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do it this way :

```
int n = 4;
char matrixA[n][n];
int i,j;

for(i = 0;i < n ;i++){
  for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
    fflush(stdin);
    matrixA[i][j] = getche();
    printf(" ");
   }
  printf("\n");
}
```

**Note that,you won't have to hit return after typing the character when you'll input.And the input will be row by row and with spaces between the characters.So,It'll give you a clear idea which value is going to which position of the matrix.

Comment: Have you specified the value of n?